# Grails 3 logging in src folder not injecting log object

Tags: grails, grails3

In the src folder of the grails 3 app:

[image]

I have a lot of `log.xyz` and they are is throwing the following exception:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: log for class: com.myApp.runner.RunnerThreadPoolExecutor
```

Which seems odd as this is a migrated app from grails 2 and having the log object in those classes was very useful.

I can add the following to each class:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeClass.class)
```

But this seems very long winded and a bit a backwards step. 
Am I missing something in the configuration somewhere?

Comment: Grails 3 uses logback by default, do you have a `/grails-app/conf/logback.groovy` file? http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#logging

Comment: I do - thanks for the link, it seems to confirm @SaschaFrinken answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add the `slf4j annotation` to your classes:

```
package com.example

import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j

@Slf4j
class MySample {
   def test() {
      log.debug("log this!")
   } 
}
```

Comment: This makes it a lot easier but I have about 150 classes.  I was wondering if there is a way/ setting  to have it working like grails 2 with the log object automatically in those classes.